# exponential time to receive messages to remote service

Tags: android, service, message-queue, android-handler

Why are messages sent at the same time taking so long between replies?

> update : I also checked the time the service received messages. And it turns out that the service receives the messages in exponential time, the time to send the reply is about constant. So why does the system send the messages to the service in such a manner?
>
> update2: this is not code, per se. More an abstraction or pseudocode missing non-relevant lines

**Client Activity:**

```
Messenger mMessenger // this Activity's messenger
Messenger mService   // Service Messenger initialised through binding

onClick(View view) {
    for(i=0; i<100; i++) {
        callMessage();
    }
}

callMessage() {
    Message msg = Message.obtain(null, 1234, 0, 0);
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putLong("sent", new Date().getTime());
    msg.setData(data);
    msg.replyTo = mMessenger; //this.Handler
    try {
        mService.send(msg);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

// in Handler
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    long now = new Date().getTime();
    long timeelapsed = now - msg.getData().getLong("sent");
    updateTextView(timeelapsed);
}
```

**Remote Service:**

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    // create a new message reply
    reply.getData().putLong("sent",msg.getData().getLong("sent"));
    msg.replyTo.send(reply);
}
```

**Results:**

(milliseconds)
54
96
135
...
...
606
...
...
1568
...
...
and so on

Comment: what is mService? what does mService.send(msg); do?

Comment: mService is the Service Handler obtained through Binding, mMessenger is the activity's messenger sent to the service. Updated the code to reflect that.

Comment: so your Service is not a remote Service?  only your app can bind to it?

Comment: the question CLEARLY states that it is a remote service!!!

Comment: post the complete code of your Activity and your Service